# mysql query alteration

Tags: mysql

**EDIT : ONE small alter to be done in this query.
That is i need to display the result in following format:**

**1. Where totalDealsBought less than maxBuy should display FIRST.**

How can this be done?

```
SELECT d.id, d.dealTitle, d.expiryDate, d.dealMainImage, d.actualPrice, d.discount, d.offerValue, d.maxBuy, sum( sc.quantity ) AS totalDealsBought
    FROM deal AS d
    LEFT JOIN shoppingcart AS sc ON sc.dealID = d.id
    WHERE CURDATE( ) != d.startDate
    AND d.startDate < CURDATE( )
    AND d.status = 'Active'
    AND d.cities = 'chennai'
    AND sc.paymentStatus = 'paid'
    GROUP BY d.id
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
... AND sc.paymentStatus = 'paid'
    GROUP BY d.id
    ORDER BY totalDealsBought, maxBuy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
... GROUP BY d.id 
    ORDER BY (totalDealsBought < d.maxBuy) DESC
```